# Como funciona a Assinatura Digital no Sistema de Saúde?

Tags: certificado-digital, assinatura-digital

A mais de um mês tenho feito a busca sobre esse assunto mas até agora não encontrei quase nada sobre o assunto, alguém saberia me explicar como funciona, depois de adquirir um e-CPF como o Windows reconheceria... Procuro principalmente para Assinatura de Laudos Médicos, e queria seguir o padrão da SBIS (Sociedade Brasileira de Informárica em Saúde), obrigado!

Comment: Marcelo, fechei a pergunta por considerar que não é sobre programação. A sua pergunta anterior, sobre e-CPF, é até parecida com esta, mas lá as dúvidas são mais claras e técnicas. Aqui parece que a dúvida é mais sobre como instalar um certificado no Windows? Se não for, por favor esclareça a pergunta, acrescentando mais detalhes. Então comente aqui que eu avalio a possibilidade de reabrir, ok?

Comment: Certo, entendo o motivo do fechamento da pergunta, realmente não se trata de programação, minha questão não é sobre instalação. Como não tenho o contato nem com um cartão e nem com a leitora, não sei como funciona, em breve quero implementar no sistema, mas não faço ideia de como isso funciona, como vou realizar a integração, como pegar os dados. Não consegui achar muito conteúdo sobre isso na internet, resolvi perguntar aos desenvolvedores como eu, que talvez alguns já utilizaram e sabem a respeito.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, não sei ao certo, mais como informou sobre e-CPF, deve ser parecido com o esquema de uma empresa que tem seu CNPJ e certificado digital para emitir notas validas(NF-e), o certificado digital funcionaria com este e-CPF, que roda algum tipo de criptografia sobre os dados afim de protege-los e torna-los acessíveis somente com a credencial chave, que no caso seria o e-CPF.

Trabalho desenvolvendo aplicações fiscais, resumidamente funciona assim, se necessito informar, alterar, modificar ou outra operação com dados fiscais da empresa X oficialmente na receita federal, primeiro necessito, formatar os dados no padrão que são aceitos, e assinala-los, rodar um algoritmo que usa como base o certificado digital da empresa X, que tem uma muitas informações que servem como uma hash para gerar a assinatura no documento fiscal e por fim torna-lo valido e verdadeiro.

---

No caso no e-CPF,a instalação do dock ubs para o cartão basta. Porque por exemplo, se você entrar no site do tal orgão, e ele solicitar um certificado de sua máquina para autenticar sua sessão no site, ele automaticamente busca se a há um certificado válido. A instalação do certificado é válida para os certificados tipo A1. Sobre os usuários pode variar, depende de sua necessidade, se vai ficar em um server se todos usuários da tal máquina irão efetudar operações com o tal certificado ou só uma pessoa. Se for um usuário só, no próprio user, caso contrário instalação da máquina. Lembrando que o tipo de certificado A3 só exige a instalação do driver do dock usb que você vai plugar o cartão, a partir dai as aplicações conseguem visualizar ele.

Comment: Obrigado pelas informações, mas tenho mais algumas perguntas: 
-Como o Windows reconhece esse e-CPF (Cartão ou Token)

Comment: Sim certo, certamente você consegue ver um chip que tem em seu e-CPF certo, certamente o tipo do seu cartão é A3,se usa um adaptador ubs, tipo esse desta imagem deste link: http://www.fecomerciomg.org.br/certificadosdigitais/assets/uploads/produtos/leitoraecpf.jpg

Comment: Ele instala automaticamente o Certificado ou no meu caso, o usuário deve instalar? O Certificado vem com uma Chave Privada e uma Publica ou devo gerar a Pública?